# Update edited values in a jtable to mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, swing

```
JTable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(resultaat));
```

// what is the easiest way  of updating edited values in the JTable to the mysql database.

-Jtable listener?
code above is only the way the data is inserted into the JTable

Answer (score 5):

I would use TableModelListener. Check [the official tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#modelchange) 
for more details